# Arduino mega + GPS module

Tags: gps, arduino

I'm using an Arduino Mega with a GPS module (PMB-648 GPS), I can see everything that the GPS sends to me:

```
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E

$GPRMC,144547.705,V,5458.6542,N,00136.4148,W,,,240512,,,N*65

$GPGGA,144549.705,5458.6542,N,00136.4148,W,0,00,,20.6,M,47.8,M,,0000*51
```

This is ok, but now I need to isolate the string that begins with "$GPRMC" and put it into another variable, the string change when the GPS change position, only the "$GPRMC" remains.

this is my code:

```
String GPSstring ="";
boolean stringComplete = false;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial2.begin(4800);
}

void loop(){
if (stringComplete){
  Serial.println(GPSstring);
  GPSstring = "";
  stringComplete = false;


  }

 }


void serialEvent2(){
  while(Serial2.available()){
  char inchar = (char)Serial2.read();
  GPSstring += inchar;

  if(inchar == '\n'){
    stringComplete = true;

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

easiest way would be to create a [StringObject](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) and use the [startsWith()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringStartsWith) method.

Answer (score 1):

It pays to be lazy. Take a look at the [TinyGPS Library](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygps) for ARduino to parse your NMEA strings easily.